# Remove dropdown item from dropdown once selected

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdownbutton, flutter-dropdownbutton

I am implementing a DropDownButtonFormField() which contains a list of items.

```
 final dropDownItems = repairIssues!
    .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
        child: Text(
          e,
          style: theme.largeSubtitleTextStyle,
        ),
        value: e))
    .toList();

DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
  child: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
    autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12, vertical: 12),
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
      ),
      isDense: true,
    ),
    hint: Text(
      PgaLocalization().msg()!.selectAnIssue,
      style: theme.largeSubtitleTextStyle,
    ),
    value: null, <-- the value is set null always
    isDense: true,
    onChanged: (value) {
      
      provider.addRepairIssue(value!); <--- addind item in separate array
      
    },
    validator: (value) {
      if (provider.arrSelectedRepairIssues.isEmpty) {
        return 'Please select an issue to continue.';
      }

      return null;
    },
    items: dropDownItems,
  ),
);
```

The `addRepairIssue()` is my provider class.

```
List<String>? _repairIssues; <--- getting data from server
List<String>? get repairIssues => _repairIssues;

List<RepairIssue> _arrSelectedRepairIssues = [];
List<RepairIssue> get arrSelectedRepairIssues => _arrSelectedRepairIssues;
addRepairIssue(String val) {
  _arrSelectedRepairIssues.add(val);
  _repairIssues!.removeWhere((element) => element != val);
  notifyListeners();
}
```

When user select any item from the list...

- That should be removed from the dropdown item
- I am storing selected item separately in an array.

so when i try to remove the item from the drop down item it gives me following error.

══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

```
The following assertion was thrown building Builder(dirty, dependencies: [_FocusInheritedScope]):
There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButtonFormField]'s value: String.
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value
'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart':
Failed assertion: line 976 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                return item.value == value;
              }).length == 1'
```

I know that the value of the dropdown should be either `null` or the value from the items;

In the above code, you can see that I am keeping `value: null` always.

How can I fix this error?

Or is there any other widget in Flutter by which I can achieve the above case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems you are actually adding it not to a separate list but to the ones that make up the items of your dropdown, but it's hard to judge without seeing the code. The error lies most likely in `addRepairIssue`

Comment: `addRepairIssue` method just add an item in array. It is independent array and nothing to do it with items showing in dropdown.

Comment: added `addRepairIssue()` code.

Comment: I would think you would want to do `_repairIssues!.removeWhere((element) => element == val);`, so `==` instead of `!=`. Although I don't think it explains the bug, but who knows, maybe changing that helps

Comment: I need to remove the item which is being added to another error. That's why `==` is used to remove that selected item in dropdown.

Comment: I'm telling to you actually use `==`. You aren't using it now